# Gstreamer Tee/Queue multiple pipelining

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe, gstreamer, tee

so I'm using gstreamer for java and I'm trying to playback live video stream and record it at the same time. right now, I could do one at a time, but I'm not sure how to do them both at the same time. I tried threading it, but there was a conflict since both of the threads were trying to access the same resource. THen, my ta told me that I need to use a tee and queues, basically, have all of the different paths share the same resources instead of trying to control it (thats what I think), I'm not sure how to do this in java though, and right now the internet doesnt have a good tutorial for java about tees... (looked through a bit, all it is is code that doesnt compile on my machine) heres an idea of what i was doing

```
public class Main { 
private static Pipeline pipe;
private static Pipeline pipeB;
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    args = Gst.init("SwingVideoTest", args); 




    pipe = new Pipeline("pipeline");
    pipeB = new Pipeline("pipeline");

    final Element tee = ElementFactory.make("queue", null);
    Element queue0 = ElementFactory.make("queue", null);
    Element queue1 = ElementFactory.make("queue", null);
    AppSink appsink = (AppSink)ElementFactory.make("appsink", null);

    tee.set("silent", "false");
    appsink.set("emit-signals", "true");

    final Element videosrc = ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "source");
    videosrc.set("device" , "/dev/video1");

    final Element colorspace = ElementFactory.make("ffmpegcolorspace", "colorspace");
    final Element videofilter = ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "flt"); 
    videofilter.setCaps(Caps.fromString("video/x-raw-yuv,  width=640, height=480, framerate=10/1"));

    final Element enc = ElementFactory.make("ffenc_mpeg4", "Encoder");
    final Element mux = ElementFactory.make("avimux", "muxer");

    final Element sink = ElementFactory.make("filesink", "File sink");
    sink.set("location", "./test.avi");


    final Element videosrcB = ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "source");
    videosrcB.set("device" , "/dev/video0");
    final Element videofilterB = ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "flt"); 
    videofilterB.setCaps(Caps.fromString("video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480"));



   VideoPlayer threadA = new VideoPlayer("screen", videosrcB, null, videofilterB, null, null, null, pipe);
   VideoPlayer threadB = new VideoPlayer("recorder", videosrc, colorspace, videofilter, enc, mux, sink, pipeB);


   threadA.run();
   threadB.run();
}




public class VideoPlayer implements Runnable{

private String playerType;
private Element videosrc, colorspace, videofilter, enc, mux, sink;
private Pipeline pipe;

VideoPlayer(final String playerType, final Element videosrc, final Element colorspace, final Element videofilter, final Element enc, final Element mux, final Element sink, final Pipeline pipe){
        this.playerType = playerType;
        this.videosrc = videosrc;
        this.colorspace = colorspace;
        this.videofilter = videofilter;
        this.enc = enc;
        this.mux = mux;
        this.sink = sink;
        this.pipe = pipe;
}

public void run(){
    VideoComponent videoComponent = new VideoComponent(); 

    Element videosink = videoComponent.getElement(); 



    if(playerType.equals("screen")){

        System.out.println(playerType);

        pipe.addMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);

        Element.linkMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Video Test"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.add(videoComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        videoComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480)); 
        frame.pack(); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        // Start the pipeline processing 

        pipe.setState(State.PLAYING);
    }

    else if(playerType.equals("recorder")){

        System.out.println(playerType);


        pipe.addMany(videosrc,  colorspace, videofilter, enc, mux, sink);
        Element.linkMany(videosrc,  colorspace, videofilter,  enc, mux, sink);    

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Video Test"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.add(videoComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        videoComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480)); 
        frame.pack(); 
        //frame.setVisible(true); 

        pipe.setState(State.PLAYING);
    }
}
```

kinda lengthy but pretty easy to see what I was trying do. If anyone could tell me how to implement the tee (I tried?) that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't create two Video Sources as you did. `videosrc & videosrcB`.

Basically, you should receive data from `videosrc` and give it to `GstTee` now the Tee must have two SrcPads. This will allow two paths to function separately.

The first src path should get connect to your `enc` and `mux` which will go on to recording And the second path will take up to the display. All should work simultaneously.

The `Tee` can be buffered by `Queue` in each path. From the point of view of circuit this is not essential, but it is good so that path#2 doesn't wait till path#1 finishes under a blocking call.

Here is how the circuit looks like.

[image: Circuit]